# Split string with height and width on textblock - Silverlight Window phone

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have long string and want binding to Textblock limit with width and height. I caculator height Textblock as:

```
textResult.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
double h = textResult.ActualHeight;
```

If height Textblock > height limit, I want to spit string at line in textblock have height = height limit and binding the rest to other textblock. Who can help me?